# Why are sections not numbered, when the parent template `section/subsection in toc` in beamer is set?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

I want to have numbered sections in beamer and as far as I understand I should set the `section/subsection in toc` template, as in my MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{section/subsection in toc}[sections numbered]

\begin{document}
    \frame{\tableofcontents}
    \section{Test1}
    \frame{Content1}
    \section{Test2}
    \frame{Content2}
\end{document}
```

However this does not create section numbers, as you can see:
[image: Output of MWE]

I know that I can get section numbers, if I set `\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]` but from the documentation, I don't understand why my first attempt does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's a bug in the documentation. The correct template is called

```
sections/subsections in toc
```

(note the plurals), and if you use

```
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[sections numbered]
```

you'll get the numbers as expected.

`beamer` templates use the primitive `\csname...\endcsname` construction; this has the disadvantage (in this case) that if the resulting control sequence if undefined it gets defined as `\relax`. The net effect is that something like

```
\setbeamertemplate{my made up template name}[foo bar baz]
```

does absolutely nothing.

Comment: I think you are right and because the issue is still in the latest version, I reported an issue, see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/621

Comment: And the issue was solved by https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/c9d658b46f56e752b1e8e43793863f3b781f082d